# Select multiple columns with not all columns mentioned in Groupby - Postgres v12

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table which contain review_id,product_id,ratings,reviewer_id,review_comments. The table i have is as below.
[image]

My need is quite simple but I have issues figuring it out.  Need is to get product_id, rating, reviewer_id and review_comments of the product_id which has the max value of review_id

With below query, I am able to get  product_id and review_id properly.

```
SELECT product_id,max(review_id) as review_id
    FROM public.products Group by product_id;
```

But when I try to add ratings, reviewer_id, and review_comments, it raises an error that those columns have to be part of a groupby and if I add those columns, grouping gets disturbed since I need grouping only on product_id and nothing else.

Is there a way to solve this?

My expected result should contain all row content with review_id 7,5,8 since for product_id 1 review_id 7 is highest and for product_id 2 review_id 5 is highest and for product_id 3 review_id 8 is highest.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below way-

```
select * from tablename a
where review_id =(select max(review_id) from tablename b where a.product_id=b.product_id)
```

or use `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by product_id order by review_id desc) as rn
from tablename
)A where rn=1
```

Comment: Your first solution really helped me so much. It even gave me flexibility to do join with other tables. Thanks much for sharing. Still, with an eagerness to understand and myself having lost touch with querying for quite a year, could you please tell me the logic behind that. My assumption is,another duplicate table  is created. Max of review_id from b is taken. and checked if corresponding product id is present in original table.  is it so?

Answer (score 4):

Try PostgreSQL's `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (product_id)
       product_id,
       review_id,
       rating,
       reviewer_id,
       review_comments
FROM products
ORDER BY product_id, review_id DESC;
```

This will return the first row for each `product_id` in the `ORDER BY` order.

Comment: You seem to have missed the last portion of my question, for which you require to add DESC next to review_id in the end.

Comment: Sorry, I was sloppy. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select p.product_id, p.rating, p.reviewer_id, p.review_comments
from public.products p
where not exists (
  select 1 from public.products
  where product_id = p.product_id and review_id > p.review_id
)
```